# Android: OnItemClickListener does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

I implemented my custom list but when I click an element of my list a `Toast` message should be displayed. It looks like that the `setOnItemClickListener` does not work.
Here there is the code of of my fragment layout in which there is my ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="15dp"
            android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here there is the structure of my list (each single line)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageContact"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:focusable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameSurnameContact"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:textColor="#33CC33"
                android:focusable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idContact"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:focusable="false"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here there is the mothod of my fragment that creates the layout and populate the list

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedBundle) {

    View firstAccessView;
    if(savedBundle==null) {
        firstAccessView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment_layout, null);


        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            Contact c = new Contact(idContact[i], nameSurname[i], facebookId[i], timeStamp[i]);
            this.rows.add(c);

        }

        adapter = new SearchListAdapter(getActivity(), this.rows);
        list = (ListView) firstAccessView.findViewById(R.id.listSearch);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "item selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        list.setOnScrollListener(this);

    }else{
        firstAccessView = getView();
    }
    return firstAccessView;
}
```

is there something that I missed in the `xml` files of in the `Fragment` file?

Comment: try adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your parent layout of `ListView`.

Comment: also in this way does not work

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:focusable="false"` from `ListView`.

Comment: @FF91,add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" in structure of list in first LinearLayout Tag

Comment: Sorry, where I should add this line?

Answer (score 0):

**android:focusable="false"**
Remove this line  from your listview xml file